# Detect whether Java class is loadable

Tags: java, class, dynamic, classloader

I have two programs:  one CLI program, and one GUI.  The GUI is a frontend for the CLI, but also a GUI for another program as well.

I am importing the CLI's classes and extending them in the GUI to add GUI elements to the classes, and all is great.

But now I want to split the CLI that I currently have embedded in the GUI (as an included JAR).  The JAR is in a fixed location (/opt/program/prog.jar), and the application will only be used on Linux, so I realize that this breaks traditional Java thought.

I've edited the ClassPath in the Manifest file to reflect this change, and it works fine.  However, when I remove the file, the GUI fails to load, citing not being able to load the class.

Is there a way to try to load a class and if it does not work, then do something else?  In essence, I'm trying to catch the ClassNotFound exception, but have not had any luck yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One common way to check for class existence is to just do a Class.forName("my.Class"). You can wrap that with a try/catch that catches ClassNotFoundException and decide what to do.  If you want, you could do that in a wrapper class that has a main().  You could try to load the class and if it succeeds, then call main() on the loaded class and if not, do something else.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) {
  try { 
    Class.forName("my.OtherMain");

    // worked, call it
    OtherMain.main();
  } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // fallback to some other behavior
    doOtherThing();
  }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need, but I'll need to try it when I get into work tomorrow.  Expect to be accepted sometime tomorrow morning.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to try to load a class and if it does not work, then do something else?

Assuming you had a class file in C:\ called Foo.class

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File f = new File("c:\\");
    if (f.exists()) {
        URLClassLoader CLoader;
        try {
            CLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{f.toURL()});
            Class loadedClass = CLoader.loadClass("Foo");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        }

    } else {
        //do something else...
    }

}
```